# Specify number size in gdb for print commands?

Tags: c, gdb

To play around with various additions to registers that may be 8,4,2 or 1 bytes (`rax`, `eax`, `ax`, `al`) is there a way I can specify the number of bytes of the number I'm using? For example

```
# works for 4 bytes
>>> p/x -1
$30 = 0xffffffff
>>> p/x 1
$31 = 0x1
>>> p/d 0xffffffff
$34 = -1

# can I get it to work for one byte, signed char?
>>> p/d 0xff
$35 = 255
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is to use casting to tell gdb the type of the value.

```
(gdb) p /d (char)0xff
$2 = -1
```

Comment: thanks, could you please link to a part in the docs that explains that a bit if it's there? I tried `help x` and `help p` but wasn't finding too much of help.

Comment: It's not really documented very explicitly as far as I know. The commands to [examine data](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Data.html) work on [expressions](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Expressions.html). An expression is in the context of the language being debugged. In this case, the default type for C is `int` and casting is the way to change the type of any expression.